# Pasar un parámetro tipo Objeto y dentro del método saber de que tipo es

Tags: java, mysql

Quiero pasar por parámetro el valor de un objeto, en concreto un `JTextField`, el problema me viene cuando tengo que pasar al método una fecha, que es tipo `JDataChooser`. Me gustaría poder pasar un tipo Objeto y que dentro del metodo pudiera saber si es JTextField o JDataChooser. ¿Habría alguna posibilidad?

```
private void updatePersona(JTextField value, String campo, String tipo, int id_persona){
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
        String sentencia = "UPDATE persona SET "+campo+" = ? WHERE id_persona = ?";

        pst = Login.getConnection().prepareStatement(sentencia);
        if(tipo.equals("String"))
            pst.setString(1, value.getText());
        else if(tipo.equals("int"))
            pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(value.getText()));
         else if(tipo.equals("Date"))                 
            pst.setDate(1, value.getDate());

        pst.setInt(2, id_persona);

        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataMemberCRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally{
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DataMemberCRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
}
```

El problema lo tengo en la línea que contiene  `pst.setDate(1, value.getDate());` al ser `JDataChooser` no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la operación `instanceof`, por ejemplo, la condición sería:

```
if( object instanceof JDataChooser){...
}
```

Otro modo es obteniendo el tipo de la clase como un String, todos los objetos tienen el método `getClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de pasar el tipo por String pásale un objeto clase y utiliza `Reflection` de la siguiente manera:

```
if(tipo == JDataChooser.class)
    pst.setDate(1, value.getDate());
```

Así compruebas que tipo es de la clase que estás buscando.